# CD docker container unhealthy due to "error in log file monitor. Failed to query file information."

Tags: docker

When running `docker compose up -d`, the `cd` container shows as unhealthy. It was functioning properly yesterday.

I am seeing these errors when the CD container is starting up, and I can see the site shutting down and starting back up in a continuous loop:

```
[LOGMONITOR] ERROR: Error in log file monitor. Failed to query file information. File: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs\log.20230614.143115.txt. Error: 50

[LOGMONITOR] ERROR: Error in log file monitor. Failed to query file ID. File: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs\log.20230614.143115.txt. Error: 50

2023-06-14 15:01:29 2800 15:01:19 INFO  **************************************************
2023-06-14 15:01:29 2800 15:01:19 WARN  Sitecore shutting down
2023-06-14 15:01:29 2800 15:01:19 WARN  Shutdown message: Initialization Error
2023-06-14 15:01:29 HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
2023-06-14 15:01:52 [2023-06-14T21:01:52.000Z][LOGMONITOR] ERROR: Error in log file monitor. Failed to query file information. File: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs\log.20230614.150152.txt. Error: 50
2023-06-14 15:01:52 [2023-06-14T21:01:52.000Z][LOGMONITOR] ERROR: Error in log file monitor. Failed to query file ID. File: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs\log.20230614.150152.txt. Error: 50
2023-06-14 15:02:19 2023-06-14 21:01:09 ::1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.3770 - 500 0 0 18197
```

Due to this issue, I am unable to access any of the sites.

I tried:

- Restarting Docker client
- Cleaning out the `docker/data/cd` folder
- Running `docker system prune`
- Rebuilding the containers via `docker compose up --build`

The only (inconclusive) references I could find related to this error are:

- https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/issues/125
- https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/issues/34

### EDIT - Solution

Using the information provided by others on this post, I was able to drill down and location the issue: my Web/Master/Core databases were missing from the `mssql` container entirely (despite them being present in the `\docker\data\mssql` directory), which was resulting in the error:

`Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database Sitecore.Web;requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'`

Not sure how this happened, but good to know that such database issues can cause endless restarts of CD.

Comment: You might find more useful info in the event logs. Try increasing interval in the health check (on docker compose file), in order to delay it restarting. Then use technique here to view event logs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215471/how-do-i-access-windows-eventlog-of-a-docker-container

Comment: @DeanOBrien The answer provided by Gaurav is an easier way to get to the true error message, but the method you mentioned definitely works as well!

Comment: Ok no problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your laptop, open Powershell and run "`docker container ls`". Find the container listed with an unhealthy status.

Open Docker Desktop and select the container that is unhealthy (In your case it is CD container). Note: An unhealthy container may not appear unhealthy within the Docker desktop which is why the previous "ls" command is so critical.

Check the logs. It will most likely be running the health check periodically and it will write the attempt to the logs. Here is an example of a failing CM health check:

```
GET /healthz/ready - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.2268 - 500 0 0 35126
```

Notice that the health check is trying to visit /healthz/ready and is receiving a 500 status code. This means our application is experiencing a YSOD but we cannot see it in the Sitecore logs (because Sitecore cannot even start).

Next, issue this command in the shell to view the raw output:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1/healthz/ready
```

This very quickly showed me that we had a bad reference pushed and we cleaned it up.

A similar approach can be utilized on all container types. Each container may have a slightly different health check, but this approach gets directly to the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. This is an easy and effective method to get to the root of the problem.

Comment: Glad you were able to get the issue.